# matplotlib horizontal bars with date and time python

Tags: python, matplotlib

i need to plot some chart with horizontal stacked bars.

I have some datetime data, this data equals to startTime of test(looks like startTime should be 'left' parameter in pylab.barh, for example left=startTime)
under x axis should be written date, each date should be equals to 24h on the picture you can see, how this should looks, each test should be in correct date tick:

```
startTime = [datetime.datetime(2015,3, 4, 23, 4, 17),
             datetime.datetime(2015,3, 5, 23, 4, 17),
             datetime.datetime(2015,3, 6, 23, 4, 17)]
```

I have test duration in seconds (if need i can convert seconds to datetime too); the duration will be the length of each bar.

```
testDuration = [432, 444, 753]
```

My code looks like that, but i don't know how to set left parameter as `datetime` and I don't know how to set `xTicks` as `datetime` with hours:

```
dynamicNlocator = 24

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8)) # height and width of chart
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.120, right=0.98)
fig.canvas.set_window_title(u'Eldorado K-8 Fitness Chart')
pos = np.arange(numCp)+0.5 # Center bars on the Y-axis ticks

rects = pylab.barh(pos, testDuration, align=u'center', left=startTime, height=0.5, color=u'm', label=u"Actual start Time")

box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1,
                  box.width, box.height * 0.9])
ax1.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.08),
           fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)

ax1.axis([0, 100, 0, numTest]) 
pylab.yticks(pos, testName, size=13)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(dynamicNlocator))
```

Right now I can't move needed test to the correct date, the chart should looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So are you trying to draw something similar to a [gant chart](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gantt+chart&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ltn-VNyeNuu67ga70YDQBw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)? There is a blog post detailing how to do it [here](http://www.clowersresearch.com/main/gantt-charts-in-matplotlib/).